# Install python package in docker file

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

In my docker file, I want to install med2image python package (https://github.com/FNNDSC/med2image). I use the following code:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3.5 \
    python3-pip \
    && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow
RUN pip install med2image
```

But I get the following error when I want to build the image:

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/e5/948b023c7feb72adf7dfb26d90a13c838737bbf52be704f5ddd0878e3264/med2image-1.1.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Sorry, only Python 3.5+ is supported.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in  /tmp/pip-install-FnNb_S/med2image/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install med2image' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What should I do?!

Comment: Try adding the following to set python3 as default https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3 (in particular the `update-alternatives` way)

Comment: I would suggest to use [that base image](https://store.docker.com/images/python) instead (`FROM python:3` aka `FROM python:3.6.5`)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### Recommended base image

As suggested in my comment, you could write a Dockerfile that looks like:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow med2image
    # Note: we had to merge the two "pip install" package lists here, otherwise
    # the last "pip install" command in the OP may break dependency resolution…

CMD ["cat", "/etc/os-release"]
```

And the command example above could confirm at runtime (`docker build --pull -t test . && docker run --rm -it test`) that this image is based on the GNU/Linux distribution "Debian stable".

### Generic `Dockerfile` template

Finally to give a comprehensive answer, note that a good practice regarding Python dependencies consists in specifying them *in a declarative way* in a dedicated text file (in alphabetical order, to ease review and update) so that for your example, you may want to write the following file:

> `requirements.txt`

```
matplotlib
med2image
nibabel
pillow
pydicom
```

> and use the following generic `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py"]
```

To be more precise, this is the approach suggested in the documentation of the Docker official image [`python`](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), §. [*How to use this image*](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/python#how-to-use-this-image)

Comment: When `RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip` is used, then does it re-use the same layer or does it create new layer (so effectively use upgrade)?

Comment: (maybe `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` is unneeded, but) I confirm that the 2 commands concatenated with a `&&` (`RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`) do create a single layer. See also the SO question [Purpose of specifying several UNIX commands in a single RUN instruction in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59535609/9164010)

Comment: prefere a single `pip install` command or you might break dependency resolution

Comment: @Gaetan I guess you talk about the`RUN` command, but can you be more specific? which exact command would you recommend?

Comment: BTW AFAICT, `pip` and dependency resolution is not very robust: (independently of this Docker context) I often stumbled on a `pip install` command that went through successfully, unlike a subsequent `pip check`…

Comment: Appart from the `pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip` that needs to be in its own, you need to do pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow med2image` for instance in a single command or the resolution on the second call of pip install might break something installed in the first (happened)

Comment: @Gaetan OK I see what you meant, thanks! Actually the code `pip install --no-cache-dir nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow && pip install --no-cache-dir med2image` was not a recommendation of mine, it was directly taken from the OP's question… and I agree it's way better to merge the two package lists (as I suggest in the last generic template). I'll edit my answer anyway to make this clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 43):

Some of the other answers/comments are suggesting to change your base image but if you want to keep your ubuntu 16.04 you can also simply specify your version of pip/python to use `pip3` or `pip3.5` like shown below.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3.5 \
    python3-pip \
    && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow
RUN pip3 install med2image
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the image smaller?

Answer (score 5):

Try pip3

```
RUN pip3 install nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow
RUN pip3 install med2image
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have Jupyter Notebook in your docker container, you can install any python package by running a new <kbd>Terminal</kbd> in Jupyter by clicking the button shown here:

[image: button for terminal]

and running: `pip install <package-name>`

The package stays in the docker container even after you exit the container.