# How to get my docker file to copy requirements.txt and expose the ports properly

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

So I am trying to dockerize a Discord bot I built. In the picture are my file structure and Dockerfile. The problem I have is that it doesn't copy `requirements.txt`.

Actually, I was watching a video on how to do it, but I ran into this problem. This is the first Dockerfile I have made.

What I aim to do: copying the whole file structure as is and when the image starts, it runs `bot.py`.

[image]

This is the Dockerfile written out.

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /Helix

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 3306:3306
EXPOSE 443:443
EXPOSE 50:50

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install libasound-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev -y \
 && pip install pyaudio

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "bot.py"]
```

The error that I keep getting is:

```
I:\HELIX\Modules\Discord\Helix>docker build -t sinless777/helix_bot - < Dockerfile
failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid.
[+] Building 1.7s (7/11)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 468B                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3                                                                                           1.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CANCELED [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:437585501d11ef4b4b831cf8a6d6611eb526e327006d506bcedcfdea3fde442a                            0.3s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:437585501d11ef4b4b831cf8a6d6611eb526e327006d506bcedcfdea3fde442a                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:437585501d11ef4b4b831cf8a6d6611eb526e327006d506bcedcfdea3fde442a 2.60kB / 2.60kB                                                        0.0s
 => => sha256:3d11a72c123ffc9326b86ad432480cef0ab73f02b7ed684873c2f8c35ce9a79f 2.22kB / 2.22kB                                                        0.0s
 => => sha256:4246fb19839fd033a0dd925c1f89cd1ad482c6b703d56f34bf0d2808b076e132 8.61kB / 8.61kB                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] WORKDIR /Helix                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [3/7] COPY requirements.txt ./                                                                                                              0.0s
------
 > [3/7] COPY requirements.txt ./:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error you get, the crux of the issue is this line:

```
COPY /requirements.txt /requirements.txt
```

which should be replaced with:

```
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

or equivalently with:

```
COPY requirements.txt ./
```

→ the first filename is a relative path w.r.t. [*the Docker build context*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description)
→ the second path is relative to the target working directory (`WORKDIR`)

#### Extra remarks

As an aside, note that the header of your Dockerfile is awkward:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.9.4
```

should be replaced with:

```
FROM python:3.9.4
```

The rule of thumb is: each Dockerfile should contain only one `FROM` command (unless you want to use [the so-called *multi-stage build* feature](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)).

Finally, there are a few optimizations that can be seen as mandatory for your Dockerfile, e.g., the lines:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libasound-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev -y
RUN pip install pyaudio
```

should be merged in:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install libasound-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev -y \
 && pip install pyaudio
```

and the two lines:

```
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

should be swapped to:

```
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

For more details on the underlying issues, you might be interested in these two other answers of mine:

- [Purpose of specifying several UNIX commands in a single RUN instruction in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535818/9164010)
- [Install python package in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50339110/9164010)

#### Update after the [OP's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69997404/revisions):

Finally it seems that the remaining issue comes from the fact your docker-build command is not correct:

Can you try replacing

```
docker build -t sinless777/helix_bot - < Dockerfile
```

with

```
docker build -t sinless777/helix_bot .
```

?

Comment: I have made your suggested edits however I receive the same error. Thus I have updated the post with the current docker file and error output.

Comment: OK! FYI, it seems the very last issue comes from your `docker build …` command → as you had written `docker build -t … - < Dockerfile`, the context did not contain the `requirements.txt` file; hence the error… (see the last edit of my answer)