# How to pass args to docker run for python?

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

I edit my Dockerfile from the feedback I received.
I run my python script with args `python3 getappVotes.py --abc 116 --xyz 2 --processall`
This is my Dockerfile. I can build successfully but not sure how I can pass above args during docker run. Arguments are optional.

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install \
        parse \
        argparse \
        datetime \
        urllib3  \
        python-dateutil \
        couchdb  \
        realpython-reader
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/appvoteslog/
COPY getappVotes.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./getappVotes.py"]
CMD ["--xx 116", "--yy 2", "--processall"]
```

Comment: You seem to be installing standard library packages with `pip`, that's not necessary. Typically you'd include a `requirements.txt` so you don't have to list them all out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks!! I will do that once I figure out the issue.

Comment: You need to use both `ENTRYPOINT` (for the program and mandatory arguments) and `CMD` (for optional arguments). Your question is certainly a duplicate, BTW ;-)

Comment: See e.g. this SO answer: [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408777/9164010)

Comment: @ErikMD I updated my Dockerfile and now I am getting this error - `error: unrecognized arguments: --xx 116 --yy 2`

Comment: @user557657 OK so I'll comment on your Dockerfile in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, for your use case, you need to use both `ENTRYPOINT` (for the program and mandatory arguments) and `CMD` (for optional arguments).

More precisely, you should edit your Dockerfile in the following way:

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install \
        parse \
        argparse \
        datetime \
        urllib3  \
        python-dateutil \
        couchdb  \
        realpython-reader
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/appvoteslog/
COPY getappVotes.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./getappVotes.py"]
CMD ["--xx", "116", "--yy", "2", "--processall"]
```

(as from a shell perspective, `--xx 116` is recognized as two separated arguments, not a single argument)

For more details:

- see the answer [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408777/9164010);
- see also the example from this answer: [Install python package in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50339110/9164010) − where the "manual" command `python -m pip install …` is replaced with a more idiomatic command, `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I tried both but didnt separate the arguments and thats why it was failing. Let me try. Thanks!!